# How to set the value of DbCommand.CommandTimeout property in web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to set the DbCommand.CommandTimeout property in one place as i dont need to call the DbCommand.CommandTimeout property everytime when i create a connection with sql.

Please let me know, if i can do some thing in web.config file or something else like that.

Answer (score 0):

As the connect timeout for establishing the connection is different from command execution timeout, either you set it manually each time or make a static method call it from there

Please see this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1389167.aspx?How+to+set+timeout+property+to+Connection+String+in+web+Config+) and [this answer](http://forums.asp.net/post/2967630.aspx) fits your request